# Remove links from list view group headers?

Tags: document-library, header

I put a custom list on a page then went to "Group By" under Modify View and selected 'Branch' (a column in the list). The list displays like this:

Branch: Financial (3)

Branch: Operations (5)

Clicking on 'Branch:' expands the list to show the items in that Branch. The names of the branches (Financial, Operations, etc.) have links on them. How do I get rid of those links and leave the text? Should I use XSL? jQuery? Something else?

I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('a[href*="c2fb4162"]').contents().unwrap();
}
```

Also tried:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
id="name"
version="version"
extension-element-prefixes="list"
exclude-result-prefixes="list">
<xsl:value-of select="@Branch" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coworker helped me figure it out. I forgot the end parenthesis and semicolon. The code below worked. "c2fb4162" was part of the list ID in the link on the headers.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('a[href*="c2fb4162"]').contents().unwrap();
});
```

Comment: Can you tell me which part of the list ID?